# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString removing additional character

Tags: ios, nsstring

Trying to get `UITextField` work with currency (all examples I saw on Stackoverflow work fine only with U.S. regional settings but fail with others).

So, I want to remove currency symbol from `NSString`,

```
    NSLog(text);
    text = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:numberFormatter.currencySymbol withString:@""];
    NSLog(text);
```

but on output I get that not only currency symbol ( kr) is removed but character(5) after it:

```
0 kr5
0
```

Comment: NSLog takes a string literal argument.

Comment: Sorry? There is no problem with NSLog, because text is NSString type